# Catch-ALL Commonly asked questions about htaccess redirects

Tags: discussion

Constantly we are having questions such as how can I redirect old sub folder to a new folder, or how can I redirect one folder to another. The only difference between these are the folder names that the poster is asking about i.e /old-shop/ to /new-shop or /wordpress/ to /joomla/.

My suggestion is that could we not have a catch all for commonly asked redirects for such situations, of course its impossible to have a catchall for all situations and this is by far not what I'm asking for.. As I feel that complex ones with removal of strings and so forth merit the question being posted. So my suggestion/question is for the most basic and common redirects using htaccess.

Question has been added here: [What are the most commonly used and basic Apache htaccess redirects?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects). Will add some typical answers shortly.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Are you offering to write it up?

Comment: Yep, will action later

Comment: Just need to pop to the damn library as my printer went Kaboom! and HP gonna take 21 days to post out a new one! ;(

Comment: Hmm, if I answer my own question does it automatically accept? something new and haven't done before...

Comment: It doesn't automatically accept. You would still need to do that manually if you wanted to.

Answer (score 4):

There is a drawback: you cannot close other questions as duplicates of a catch-all question. Should the asker scroll through a long list of answers not relevant for his problem?

We had a [similar topic on WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18968/best-collection-of-code-for-your-htaccess-file). It was a desaster.

Very popular for some visitors, but completely useless as a dupe target.

My suggestion: Write **one** canonical answer for each problem (hotlinking, redirect to subdomain etc.) on **separate** questions. This will work better for moderators and askers.

Comment: Sadly your still get duplicates either doesn't stop it.

Comment: @bybe Duplicates are inevitable. No matter what you try. Some users just don’t search.

Comment: Compromise: Perhaps "we" could generate separate Q/A pairs for each issue and use the existing catch-all answer to link out to individual Q/A pairs? (... and by "we" I mean bybe - won't count for rep as community wiki Q/A's but will still count toward your badges as others find them useful)